# Create a Function in sql server without specifying return_data_type

Tags: sql-server-2008, datatypes, functions, parameter

I am trying to create a Scalar-valued function in SQL server, without specifying the return_data_type

i want to be able to return any datatype based on a parameter sent by the function caller

e.g.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GenerateRandomData 
(
    @Datatype varchar(20)
)
RETURNS <Return any datatype specified by @Datatype parameter>
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    IF @Datatype in ('varchar','char','nchar','nvarchar','text','ntext')
        Begin
            RETURN 'String'
        end
    Else
    IF @Datatype in ('int','bigint','smallint')
        Begin
            RETURN 100
        end
    Else
    IF @Datatype in ('datetime','smalldatetime')
    Begin
        RETURN getdate()
    end     

END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

The return datatype must be specified in a function. It is not an optional part of [the grammar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx). You can return [`sql_variant`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx) though.